# D3 -Is there a way of calculating the frequency of ID's that occur with a specific value from a dataset

Tags: json, d3.js

Im trying to create a histogram/bar-chart with d3 using JSON formatted data to add to the dashboard of an existing project. My data has 2 fields: ID & changes(which represents nr of changes specific to that id).

The histogram should have on the y-axis: changes : 0-10-20-30-40-50-60-70-80-80-100

However my issue is that I don't know how to get the data I need to display on the X-Axis. The X-Axis should be "count of id's with X amount of changes" so i should group the number of ID'S with 0-9 changes in the first bar of the histogram, nr of ID's with 10-19 changes in the second, nr of ID's with 20-29 changes in the third bar etc...

The data:

```
[{"id":1,"changes":59},
{"id":2,"changes":88},
{"id":3,"changes":69},
{"id":4,"changes":28},
{"id":5,"changes":75},
{"id":6,"changes":78},
{"id":7,"changes":18},
{"id":8,"changes":90}
...]
```

This is what I have so far but am unsure where I would carry out the calculation to group the number of ID's with changes:10-20 for example

```
    //x-Scale
const render = data => {
    const xValue = d => d.id;
    const yValue =d => d.changes;
    const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, xValue), d3.max(data, xValue)])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);


    // Y-SCALE 
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(data, yValue), d3.max(data, yValue)])
    .range([500, 0]);

    // GOUPING
    const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);


    g.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
    g.append('g').call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
        .attr('transform', `translate(0,502)`);

    // RECTANGLES (BARS)
    g.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('height', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
    .attr('width', d => xScale(xValue(d)));  
};

d3.json('mock.json')
  .then(function(data) {
      render(data);
      console.log(data[0]);
  });
```

Comment: Take a look at [`d3.histogram()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v1.2.4/README.md#histograms). It will return an array of bins, which I think is what you’re looking for.

Comment: @Noleli Thanks I have looked at that not quite what I was looking for but I think the problem is also me articulating the problem I have